# Sample size formula for multiple regression between binomial variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, sample-size, statistical-power

Let's say we have k binomial variables, and a sample size of n observations per variable, where each variable occurs (positive case) at a given frequency/probability f.  We would like to check if there is a correlation between these variables, so the null hypothesis assumes that they are all independent (no correlation).

**Is there a formula to calculate the minimum sample size n required to identify a "significant" correlation (p <= alpha) between these variables?**

That is, *how are n, k, f and alpha linked to each other mathematically?*

Are any other parameters involved in the formula, e.g., beta, $R^2$, etc.?

I have a feeling that this relates to power and/or sample size calculations for multiple logistic regression, but I'm really not sure. Could the Wald test or likelihood-ratio test be used here?

Comment: What exactly is involved in your "multiple regression," given you have assumed these variables are *independent*?  Why do you need to identify a correlation when you have explicitly assumed there is none?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the null hypothesis assumes there is no correlation, but that is what we are trying to test. (original post now edited).

Comment: Thank you.  Since it's a little strange to be analyzing vectors of binomial variables using correlation, could you explain the purpose of this and perhaps describe what these variables represent?

Comment: Yes, for example, how many individual human genomes (n) do we need to study to see if there is a correlation between k genetic mutations, where each mutation occurs at the same frequency f?